# how can i delete all records acc. to ViewID in mvc

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

```
Id          ViewId                        ColumnName
1   4C3A2B7A-A901-4906-BFAB-514D94395140    A
2   4C3A2B7A-A901-4906-BFAB-514D94395140    B
3   4C3A2B7A-A901-4906-BFAB-514D94395140    C
4   4C3A2B7A-A901-4906-BFAB-514D94395140    D
5   4C3A2B7A-A901-4906-BFAB-514D94395140    E
```

please tell me how can I delete all records acc. to `ViewID` in mvc5. I am using this code :

```
db.ViewXColumnIndexes.RemoveRange(db.ViewXColumnIndexes.Where(x => x.ViewId == viewId)); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

but it's not working..please tell me asap.

Comment: Try a tolist on the where

Comment: not working my friend

Comment: Does it just do nothing or throw an error or what?  It looks fine.

Comment: nothing my friend,problem is that ,when I am debugging than I am not getting any error,,,so I am not getting what's main problem ..